# Help Converting Apache htaccess to Nginx Rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to convertthe following Apache htaccess rules to **Nginx Rewrite rules**:

Redirect 301 /feed.php http://www.example.com/feed/

Thanks very much~

Answer (score 3):

Formatting's a bit off, but I assume your original rule was

```
Redirect 301 /feed.php http://www.example.com/feed/
```

so the Nginx rewrite would be

```
rewrite ^/feed\.php http://www.example.com/feed/ permanent;
```

Not difficult if you [read the documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following bash one-liner, to convert Apache Redirect lines in the .htaccess file:

```
while read LINE; do echo -e `echo $LINE | egrep '^Redirect' | cut -d' ' -f1-2` "{\n\treturn 301 `echo $LINE|cut -d' ' -f3`;\n}"; done < .htaccess
```

As a result,

```
Redirect /feed.php http://www.example.com/feed/
```

... lines are printed to the following Nginx style:

```
location /feed.php {
         return 301 http://www.example.com/feed/;
}
```